# show a specific item from a hashmap in a listview

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, adapter

Is there a way to show only a specific element from ArrayList using an ArrayAdapter

```
   final ListView lst = (ListView)  findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            for(int j=0;j<result.length();j++) {
                try {


                    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    map.put("title", result.getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
                    map.put("url", result.getJSONObject(j).getString("url"));


                    list.add(map);



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        ArrayAdapter ad= new ArrayAdapter(List.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

        lst.setAdapter(ad);
```

in other words: I want to show only title element in a ListView.

Do I need to create a CustomAdapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#SimpleAdapter(android.content.Context,%20java.util.List%3C?%20extends%20java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20?%3E%3E,%20int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])). E.g.

```
SimpleAdapter ad= new SimpleAdapter(List.this, list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] {"title"}, new int[] {android.R.id.textview1});
```

the String[] contains the key you want to use to retrieve the values to set in your ui

Comment: `setOnItemClickListener` is a method of `ListView`. In the callback you will get, the entry at position, meaning you will get the HashMap instance, contained in your list at the specific position. Yes it will work

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do it :

1. By creating custom adapter
2. By creating another arraylist with just value you want to show. like below :

   ```
   ArrayList<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();
   for(int j=0;j<result.length();j++) {
           try {


               HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
               map.put("title", result.getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));
               map.put("url", result.getJSONObject(j).getString("url"));
               listTitle.add(result.getJSONObject(j).getString("title"));

               list.add(map);



           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

   ArrayAdapter ad= new ArrayAdapter(List.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listTitle);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a custom adapter in this case or you can simple create an additional list and use it for ArrayAdapter.

You can also create extended List for you purposes and pass HashMap into it

Answer (score 0):

if you need String.

```
String title=(String)map.get("title");
```

if you need object.

```
Object title=map.get("title");
```

Hope it works. Thanks